# How to fix 'Subscript out of range' error in Excel VBA: getting row number of target cell in change event for a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet change event that performs an action when each cell of a table column changes. For that specific action, I need to find the row number of the target cell. I have the following snippet inside the Worksheet_Change event:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    row_num = tbl.ListRows(Target.Row - tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row).Index
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

I have a separate macro that just refreshes this same table on a button click.

```
Sub Refresh()

Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Refresh
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The macro runs fine and returns the right `row_num`. However, only when the table is refreshed, the `Target.Row` value in the 1st snippet is set to the same row number as the Header row of that table, thus making `row_num` as empty and returning a 'Subscript out of range error.

Why is this happening? By specifying that the action be performed only when the target cell intersects the DataBodyRange of that table column, should it not work only for changes in the data part of the column (excluding header and totals)?

Comment: Just to clarify, so if you add a `Debug.Print Target.Row` (outside the loop), it doesn't return the correct row number?

Comment: It returns the sheet row number.

Comment: Right, but you say that `Target.Row` is the same row number as the header row of the table. Is that true or not? In other words, do you have sample values for `Target.Row` and `tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row`?

Comment: I should clarify that only when the table is refreshed that it crashes - `Target.Row` is somehow detected as the Header Row cell and an error is returned because of the way `row_num` (the table row number) is calculated and it results in `row_num=0`.
The macro runs fine if I don't refresh - `Target.Row` returns the sheet row number of the changed cell, using which the right `row_num` is identified.

Comment: Do you refresh it within the Worksheet change event?

Comment: No, the Refresh macro is separate in another module.

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row` as well. Can you confirm that it is equal to `Target.Row`? What is the value of both? What is the expected value of both?

Comment: It confirms what I've told you - `Debug.Print tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row` = `Target.Row` when table is refreshed. But when I just close and reopen file and change a cell in that table column, it returns different and correct values for both.
I think maybe the issue is the event change macro interfering with the Refresh macro? The refresh macro just needs to reset the table to original values and should ideally not trigger the event change macro. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense - but I see you've toggled `Application.EnableEvents` within the `Refresh` macro so I'm not sure why the event change is firing. That said, you could also `Debug.Print Target.Address`. My next guess is that `Target` spans both the header and the body of the table. You could check if `Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1` if you only want to trigger it on the change of a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

So I have to rescind my initial answer after testing and go a completely different way.

> By specifying that the action be performed only when the target cell
>   intersects the DataBodyRange of that table column, should it not work
>   only for changes in the data part of the column (excluding header and
>   totals)?

Correct, this portion of code will not run when the `Target` is outside the `DatabodyRange` of the 5th `Column` in `Table1`

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
row_num = tbl.ListRows(Target.Row - tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row).Index
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

> However, only when the table is refreshed, the Target.Row value in the
>   1st snippet is set to the same row number as the Header row of that
>   table, thus making row_num as empty and returning a 'Subscript out of
>   range error.

Exactly.  Assuming what you say is true and `Target.Row = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row` after refresh.  Then your code is designed such that `row_num` will not be assigned because the code above will not execute.

> Why is this happening?

The only way I can get your code to generate an out of range error is when I do what @BigBen alluded to in his final comment.  If I select a sell in or above the header row and then expand my selection to include a cell in the 5th column data bodyrange then I get your error.  You can test if this is is your problem with `Target.Cells.Count`.

Comment: But the problem line is `row_num = tbl.ListRows(Target.Row - tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row).Index`...

Comment: That's not what I read.  I read "row_num is empty", the error location was ambiguous.

Comment: Well, the only line that has `row_num` in it is the one I mentioned... It's also the only line with `Target.Row` in it.

Comment: Right, but I think the error happens above it, when the condition is being tested.

Comment: I'm not sure that line can throw a subscript out of range error.

Comment: Happy to test in about an hour when I get to a computer.